# python equivalent of vlookup for a series and a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

```
  entrydate  exitdate    ddmax    
1 2012-02-15 2012-02-17    -1        
2 2012-02-18 2012-02-19    -2       
3 2012-02-20 2012-02-21    -3     
4 2012-02-22 2012-02-22    -2      
5 2012-02-24 2012-02-24    -6
```

I wish to add a column, `df['location']=` where the result is the DATE at which ddmax occurred. This date is somewhere between the entry and exit dates.

To find this date though, I need to vlookup on another series:

```
s = 
2012-02-15   -3
2012-02-16   -1
2012-02-17   -2
2012-02-18   -2
2012-02-19   -1
2012-02-20   -1
2012-02-21   -3
2012-02-22   -2
2012-02-23   -3
2012-02-24   -6
2012-02-25   -9
```

So I lookup via the numbers, and take the relevant date

how can I do this?

I tried map function, and pd left merge, but to no avail...

expected output:

```
  entrydate  exitdate    ddmax      location  
1 2012-02-15 2012-02-17    -1      2012-02-16 
2 2012-02-18 2012-02-19    -2      2012-02-18
3 2012-02-20 2012-02-21    -3      2012-02-21
4 2012-02-22 2012-02-22    -2      2012-02-22
5 2012-02-24 2012-02-24    -6      2012-02-24
```

Comment: Ive noticed there are several duplicate values in your `s` with different dates. So you just get the date of the first occurrence ?

Comment: @RafaelC , ideally, the code would look in series defined by the date range 'entrydate' and 'exitdate', i.e. for the 1st iteration, take a subsection of 's' between '2012-02-15' and '2012-02-17'   , and look in there for the value. If in this subsection, there are duplicate values, then take the first is fine. In my actual data, I am working to 4dp so highly unlikely there would be dupes in there. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not saying this is pretty, but helps if have small data (which seems to be the case)

```
def lookup(x):
    is_ = s.loc[(s.d >= x.entrydate) & (s.d <= x.exitdate), ['i', 'd']]
    return is_.loc[is_.i == x.ddmax, 'd'].iloc[0]

df['location'] = df.apply(lookup, 1)
```

Outputs

```
    entrydate   exitdate    ddmax   location
1   2012-02-15  2012-02-17  -1  2012-02-16
2   2012-02-18  2012-02-19  -2  2012-02-18
3   2012-02-20  2012-02-21  -3  2012-02-21
4   2012-02-22  2012-02-22  -2  2012-02-22
5   2012-02-24  2012-02-24  -6  2012-02-24
```

---

The code above assumes your `s` is a data frame such as

```
    d           i
0   2012-02-15  -3
1   2012-02-16  -1
2   2012-02-17  -2
3   2012-02-18  -2
4   2012-02-19  -1
5   2012-02-20  -1
6   2012-02-21  -3
7   2012-02-22  -2
8   2012-02-23  -3
9   2012-02-24  -6
10  2012-02-25  -9
```

If you have a `pd.Series`, such as

```
d
2012-02-15   -3
2012-02-16   -1
2012-02-17   -2
2012-02-18   -2
2012-02-19   -1
2012-02-20   -1
2012-02-21   -3
2012-02-22   -2
2012-02-23   -3
2012-02-24   -6
2012-02-25   -9
Name: i, dtype: int64
```

The the `lookup` function changes a little bit, to

```
def lookup(x):
    is_ = s.loc[(s.index >= x.entrydate) & (s.index <= x.exitdate)]
    return is_.loc[is_ == x.ddmax].iloc[0]
```